# What's up with this 'R' button functionality?

Tags: discussion, support

I just came back after a 1 month ban, so bear with me if I've tried searching the keyword 'R', "R", R functionality in the search bar and have found nothing.

When did they add this to Gaming.SE? When you press R a list of things come up I assume that show your achievements? Not sure what's going on and what the intent of the feature is.

[image]

This only shows up on Gaming.SE and not any other SE site.

Comment: You can see a list of keyboard shortcuts if you use <kbd>?</kbd>

Comment: For anyone else who saw the word "genitals" in a question title and got interested, [here you go](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/why-is-the-skin-around-my-genitals-darker-than-the-rest-of-my-body).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are [keyboard shortcuts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237166), R for reputation (and other achievements). You can enable or disable them on per-site basis by going to the Settings page of your profile.